# Could the $\gamma$ ray "weaken law" be used in the air?

Tags: nuclear-physics, radiation, gamma-rays

I'd better write it down. I do not know if it is called "weaken law" in English.

$$N=N_0e^{-\mu d}$$
$N$ is the initial number of photons. $N_0$ is the amount measured after passing through an absorber . $\mu$ represent to coefficient of absorption. $d$ is the distance between radiation source and measuring point.

I guess this equation has not considered non-parallel ray diffusing in space. Maybe most shield is not thick.
If I measure the number of photon particles in the air without other shield, could it still represent the change of it.
I used this equation to fit my statics, the $R$ square is $0.88$. I am really confusing now.

Shall I use *Kerma* equation instead? It is also fitting well.

Comment: μ is normally called the coefficient of absorption in English

Comment: I wonder if [stats.se] would also be a place to consider asking this question, if it doesn't get the attention here (i.e., if you don't get an answer here, consider expanding your question to be more about the statistics aspects (which seems to be your goal) and ask it over there/have it migrated)

Comment: N0 should be the initial number of photons, and N the amount measured after passing through an absorber

Comment: This topic maybe easy to understand by the professional. I added the numerical computation result just to prove I am not come here for homework help. It is not a homework, by the way.
It has few association with statistics learn and conputation in fact.
Appreciate anyway @KyleKanos

Comment: I didn't say anything about this being homework. I said that your interest seems to be about using statistical measures to choose between two mathematical relations to describe something & opined that you might be able to get that answer elsewhere *if* you don't get one here.

Comment: That was not aimed at you @KyleKanos . It is also part of discussion apart from proof for my effort. Maybe my words misled you.I'm concerning about the scope of application of the equation.

Comment: You directed the comment to me, what else would I think about it? If your concern is the application of the equation, then you need to restructure your question to be about that. Currently, you ask "Should I use a different law because it also fits the data" which seems to me to be about which law to use based on statistical measures.

Comment: I said "in the air" in the title.

Answer (score 1):

What you have described in your post is called [Beer–Lambert law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law) or attenuation law.

Regarding your question (if I understand it correctly)- yes, your equation describe the attenuation of photon ray even in the air without any further shielding. There is no qualitative difference between the shielding made of air or lead.

But keep in mind that the attenuation equation was derived for a narrow and collimated photon beam. For a broad and poorly colimated beams, one have to introduce the buildup factor B:

[image]

The attenuation coefficient quantify the fraction of the photons of a certain energy that interact with the transport medium per unit length. In this case, interaction means any process which leads to the photon removal from the beam (absorption, scattering). The necessity of buildup factor B arise when you consider the fact, that some of the scattered photons (lost from the beam) are scattered once (or multiple times) more outside the beam and can potentially hit the detector anyway. This excess in the number of detected photons is quantified by the buildup factor.

To discuss it in more detail, please provide some info about your measurement setup - geometry, colimation, detector type (spectrometer or simple counter), parameters of the photon source, ...

Comment: Thanks,I have check some other books and it turned out that the coefficient of absorption of the air existed.That support me to use this equation in some reason.  I have gotten some help from my friend and some physics professor. I'd btter write it down as a answer since it has extra detail I have not notice before.
 I always find so much help and so much to learn when using another language, apart from the issue I am concerning.
Hope you donot feel aggressive that I used so much first person sentence, with my lame English.

Answer (score 0):

The equation you are writing is called an [exponential decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay)  in the case of lifetimes, i.e. d being the time:

A quantity is subject to exponential decay if it decreases at a rate proportional to its current value. Symbolically, this process can be expressed by the following differential equation, where N is the quantity and λ (lambda) is a positive rate called the exponential decay constant:

[image]

the solution is

[image]

> Here N(t) is the quantity at time t, and N0 = N(0) is the initial quantity, i.e. the quantity at time t = 0

It is a very accurate equation to be used for photons or any decay processes in nuclear and particle physics, as long as there is only one kind of particle decaying. If the sample radiating has photons from different atomic number  decaying nuclei it would be the sum of two exponentials and error would be introduced.

I believe that in your case , if the absorption is not from a single process ( analogous to single lifetime in decays) it would be safer to use the [KERMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerma_%28physics%29) equation

> Kerma is an acronym for "kinetic energy released per unit mass", defined as the sum of the initial kinetic energies of all the charged particles liberated by uncharged ionizing radiation (i.e., indirectly ionizing radiation such as photons and neutrons) in a sample of matter, divided by the mass of the sample. It is defined by the quotient K=dE_tr/dm.

This is an opinion of a non expert in this region, except that I know if two lifetimes are involved the single exponential decay is not correct.

Comment: Appreciate.While it is not about decay. Nor associate with time.
The problem of KERMA equation is that ,you need make sure the ionization equilibrium in the absorber. Or ,the absorber has obtained all the Sec ondary Charged Particle.

Comment: I am just making an analogy. The incremental decrease is mathematically the same. It could be that for absorption it is a good approximation to use a fixed mu characterizing the sample. If you look at the link there is a KERMA for air.